# Несколько страниц в GWT

Tags: gwt, html, java

Возможно ли в одном проекте на GWT иметь несколько html-страниц? У меня есть приложения для пользователей группы А и группы Б. Эти приложения должны располагаться на разных html-страницах. Возможно ли данная концепция в GWT? Пока у меня не получилось. Я могу одну страницу сделать как для группы А, так и для группы Б, с программным переключением, а чтоб две разные страницы были - не как.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно делать несколько страниц. К каждой подключаете GWT. Можно сделдать несколько EntryPoint'ов, если требуется разная инициализацияи и сделать entry point selector.

К сожалению, из вопроса не ясно, в чём, собственно, проблема?

Comment: Как оказалось, проблема была во мне.

Answer (score 3):

Либо еще проще - использовать один GWT модуль и сделать две разные страницы с div'ами, у которых разные id, а в EntryPoint написать нечто вроде такого:

```
RootPanel.get("admin").add(new AdminWidget());
RootPanel.get("user").add(new UserWidget());
```

Соответственно страница admin.html будет иметь элемент div с id="admin", 
а страница user.html будет иметь элемент div с id="user".
Конечно классы AdminWidget и UserWidget должны наследовать Composite, проще говоря - они должны быть простыми виджетами. По-моему, очень простое и элегантное решение.
Все сказанное выше имеет смысл, если вы не хотите делать несколько модулей.

А для того, чтоб посетители не скачивали ненужный код JS-файла в Google придумали CodeSplitter, который асинхронно загружает код в момент его вызова (отдаленно напоминает RPC-вызов). Вот ссылка:
http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html

Comment: В этом случае вес выходного js-ника будет суммироваться из двух, они у меня большие. А вообще, решение гуд.

Comment: Для того, чтоб посетитель не скачивали ненужный код JS-файла придумали CodeSplitter, который асинхронно загружает код в момент его вызова. Вот ссылка:
http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html

Comment: К сожалению, принять два ответа нельзя. За Ваш ответ огромный респект :).

Answer (score 1):

1. Либо разные сервлеты.
2. Либо с помощью [History](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html). Т.е. добавить слушатель состояния history:

   ```
   History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
     public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> e) {
       RootLayoutPanel root = RootLayoutPanel.get();
       root.clear();
       String value = e.getValue() + "";
       Widget w;
       if ("a".eqauls(value)) {
         w = new FirstModeMainWidget();
       } else if ("b".eqauls(value)) {
         w = new SecondModeMainWidget();
       } else {
         w = new YourDefaultMainWidget();
       }
       root.add(w);
     }
   });
   ```

И при запуске генерить event об изменении history-state:

```
    History.fireCurrentHistoryState()
```